# elasticsearch 5.x - Java Api - Highlighting

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do i implement highlighting with the new 5.x Version of elasticsearch Java Api?

This is my queryBuilder:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = this.client.prepareSearch...
```

In previous versions we could simply add a field to be highlighted:

```
searchRequestBuilder.addHighlightedField('name');
```

But this is not possible anymore.

Can anyone provide a quick example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `HighlightBuilder` under package `org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.subphase.highlight` and pass it to `SearchRequestBuilder`'s `highlight(HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder)` method